# SQL count Occurency trouble

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm pretty new in the SQL world and i have some troubles about counting some row. I explain myself:

I have a DB like this:

```
NAME | (somenumbers)|
L1   | 2
L1   | 2
L2   | 3
L3   | 1
L3   | 1
L3   | 1
```

I expected result like this [L1:4,L2:3,L3:3], i have tried to read and test some count, group by or distinct but I am missing something. So if some people can help me, i would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sum()` instead `count()`

```
select name,sum(somenumbers) from table_name
group by name
```

Comment: Damn it i feel dumb to bother you with that stupid little word, This work perfectly Thanks man for this fast answer !